# How to display hasMany relationships in Ember 2.2 templates

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Can't figure out why my related items aren't loading.

models/group.js

```
export default Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    slideshows: DS.hasMany('slideshow', { async: true }),
});
```

models/slideshow.js

```
export default Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    group: DS.belongsTo('group', { async: true }),
});
```

Main view:

```
{{#each groups as |group|}}
    {{slideshow-group group=group}}
{{/each}}
```

templates/components/slideshow-group.hbs

```
<li>
    <h2>{{group.name}}</h2>

    <ul>
        <li>{{group.slideshows}}</li>
        {{#each group.slideshows as |slideshow|}}
        <li>
            <h2>{{slideshow.title}}</h2>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</li>
```

This is how I'm creating records. This call is inside an RSVP to create the group so I'm sure it's been saved.

```
slideshow = this.store.createRecord('slideshow', {
    title: 'blah',
    group: group
});

group.get('slideshows').pushObject(slideshow);

slideshow.save();
```

I've tried leaving group off the slideshow, only setting group in slideshow, setting both, and calling pushObject after slideshow.save. It seems the link is only being stored in the slideshow?

The first LI shows group.slideshows as DS.PromiseManyArray and group.slideshows.length = 0 so the list is blank. If its not loading them automatically how do I make it load them?

Comment: What `<li>{{group.slideshows.length}}</li>` shows ?

Comment: When I inspect the 'slideshow' it shows a group but when I inspect the 'group' slideshows = []?

Comment: I notice you're not saving `group` after pushing the slideshow into the relationship. Also, you should only be adding slideshow after it successfully saves.